# Why are some @media queries stacked like this in Bootstrap CSS files?

Tags: css, media-queries

Why are some `@media` queries stacked like this? Wouldn't it be easier to just keep this kind of stuff all together?

I mean I get why you'd do it based on grouping in your css, but this seems redundant since they are literally inline of each other?

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .visible-xs-block {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .visible-xs-inline {
    display: inline !important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .visible-xs-inline-block {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap CSS isn’t hand-written, it’s generated from source LESS or Sass files, so it’ll be down to the preprocessor.

Comment: I think a more pressing question is, why do the authors of so many themes believe they always need `!important` in their themes.